# Animated Movie about a boy stranded on a dinosaur-filled land

Tags: animation, identify-this-movie

I don't remember too much, but for starters, if I'm not mistaken, I think I watched it after 2004, on like a Sunday Morning Block. Not sure how helpful that was, since the channel I watched it on often plays movies from really long ago. So the movie might be made on 2002, it might be made on the 1980s. I'm not sure. But the animation looks far better than old cartoons.

I'm very sure the movie was made for children. That's one thing. I think the plot involve a main character, whose name I'm pretty sure is "Tex" (Although I'm not sure if that's short for something, but that's what he's referred to throughout the movie.), who ran away from, I think home, on some kind of wooden raft, only to end up on an island filled with dinosaurs. He met this girl, whose father was a scientist? Explorer? Something like that, who lives on the island, and takes care of the baby dinos. The main antagonist I believe was some kind of shrewd guy with a dark secret lair. I think his main motive have something to do with the Dinosaur eggs, which is why they instantly concerns the cast.

At the end of the movie, the boy gets his very own dinosaur from a freshly hatched egg, while the girl gets her own dinosaur that is like a twin or something of the boy's dino, except the colors are different. Then the credits roll.

I'm not even sure this is a well known movie, so my hopes isn't too high...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Dinotopia: Quest for the Ruby Sunstone* is what you're remembering. It was released in 2005 and the main character was a boy named Kex. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0372238/

Comment: Yes! I think this is definitely it. I think I remember the lead was blonde and he wore a red jacket. I remembered the animation to be better though...